# What are PREMERGED dll in .net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

What are PREMERGED dll's and how do you get them from a build in Visual Studio?
e.g. MyApplication.PREMERGED.dll

Comment: First I've heard of it.  What makes you think a VS build can create them if you don't know what they are?

Comment: I have an existing web application from work and when I build it i see it as a PREMERGED dll in the bin folder. Have looked at the csproj and cant see anything unusual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologizes on question. It was getting the name from project\properties assembly name.